# Replace the Visual Studio Find Results

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I'm wanting to create a replacement window which displays the Find results (and maybe also Find Symbol Results in the future).

Preferably I don't want to touch the "Find dialog" and would prefer not to do the actual finding myself - just change how it is displayed.

I've found 3 Interfaces I should be able to Import - IVsFindHelper, IVsFindScope, IVsFindTarget

Any ideas of how I can get started with this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at ReSharper? It allows you to do the searches you mention plus a whole host of other things.

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

[ReSharper - Navigation and searching](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Structural_Search_and_Replace)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a big resharper fan. I use coderush, and they too had a replacement Find results, but when I last used it, it had some terrible display problems with dark themes.

In any case, To get the level of control I want, I really have to write it myself.